# Querying Language service in Visual Studio Editor Extension to get Assembly, class and method info

Tags: visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-extensions

I want to write an Editor extension for Visual Studio 2010.
In my extension I want to get information about the Class, method which is at the current caret position.

For example, if I am in an Event Handler and I have some code that shows a MessageBox using MessageBox.show(…) and the caret is at .Show, 
I want to query VS Services to get a response which tell me that I the caret is at Show method of MessageBox class which is in System.Windows.Froms.dll version 4.0.40319 etc.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this with the current APIs in Visual Studio 2010. This is why we're building the [Roslyn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/roslyn) APIs so you could. When you install the CTP, we setup a Roslyn instance that replaces the standard language services with the Roslyn ones, and you can ask your question directly to it.

If you *don't* want to be dependent upon running in the Roslyn instance (which I assume is the case), then it gets a bit trickier. You can invoke the parsers to understand you're on a call named MessageBox.Show, but to get the semantics you'd have build up a Compilation making sure you get all the project references and source files right. That's a far trickier proposition, so depending on your scenario you might want to "cheat" as much as possible.

Disclosure: I'm on the Roslyn team.